# Galleries are limited to 12 images

Tags: gallery

I have used the wordpress gallery for my posts. with 10-40 photos per gallery. Since today, however, only exactly 12 photos per gallery are displayed in the all the posts on my website. (although I have selected more photos per gallery)
Where is the error? I use Impreza. Is there a connection, because I had NexGen Gallery in my plugins, but deleted it again? Although I didn't used it.
As this is a homepage of my travels, I have around 10'000 pictures in my media-file. Would there be a maximum?